# Double Div Centering And Overlapping Using FlexBox Only

Tags: css, flexbox, center, centering

Using the flexbox method, I would like to "double center" **two separete divs:** `svg` and `text` sothat they **overlap** eachother while also centering vertically and horizontally exactly over eachothers central pivot points, no matter how tall or wide they are.

Initial state is the `svg` div is shown. When mouseover, `svg` hides and `text` shows:

## [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/59o8z7fw/13/)

Here, the first `svg` div is nicely and elegantly centered using flexbox's magical `margin: auto`

However the second `text` div uses a tedious manual positioning hack, where the height is guessed, which doesnt work when font size is changed etc.

How to make `text` centered elegantlly, overlapping `svg`, using flexbox only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross browser support, you need to use `transform: translate`, since browsers deal with absolute elements differently

```
text{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
container{
    display:flex;
    background: #DDD;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

svg {
    margin: auto; /* CENTERSsvg graphic in the middle of container WORKS ELEGANTLY */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity:1;
    fill: red;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

text{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

container:hover svg {
    opacity: 0;
}

container:hover text {
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <container>
          <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200"><rect width="200" height="200" /></svg>
          <text>Here Goes My Centered Text</text>         
    </container>
</a>
```

---

*Updated based on a comment*

To use the centering capabilities of Flexbox, one could create 2 containers, layered on top of each other, in the way we always has prior to Flexbox was available.

This solution doesn't need `translate`, it uses Flexbox to center the items both horizontally and vertically, no matter their individual size.

```css
container {
    display:flex;    
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #DDD;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
container + container{
    background: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
svg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity:1;
    fill: red;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
text{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
container:hover svg {
    opacity: 0;
}
container:hover + container text {
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <container>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <rect width="200" height="200" />
    </svg>
  </container>
  <container>
    <text>Here Goes My Centered Text</text>
  </container>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your demo, but in my FireFox 50.0 the two divs are shown side by side, instead of overlapping, which is what I want, as seen in my demo.

Comment: @Sam I can't test for FF 50.0...but what if you set `left: 0;` on the `text`? ...older browsers often need x/y value, or else they again behave different

Comment: Thanks @LGSon +1 Beautiful! Now your demo works with both divs overlapping nicely. While its now much much more elegant (+1) using css positioning, it would be awesome if we can make this work using just the centering capabilities of **flexbox, as is used in my demo to center the `svg` div with much less code**.

Comment: @Sam That can't be done today, as different browsers treat an absolute positioned element different when Flexbox is used. I will make another demo, to see if that works...will be back with that

Comment: @Sam Tried a bunch of tricks, nothing comes out as slim and perfect as what I already posted. So when you say _using just the centering capabilities of flexbox_, that is exactly what we do here, and since Flexbox wasn't meant to make neither absolute position nor transfrom obsolete, we here need to combine the 3, to achieve something neither can do alone.

Comment: @Sam I also updated my answer with a second sample, making better use of _the centering capabilities of flexbox_ :)

Comment: awesome indeed I understand the second way, and indeed this is probably the only way in flexbox, eventhough it takes up more html code. This answer is a nice example that it is not true that CSS Flexbox is always cleaner in code, as can be seen in your answer the first way is shorter code and solves the centering equally well. Thanks!